# Text "stuck" to bottom in BASH

Tags: php, bash

I'm creating a script in PHP that will run for quite a while in the command line, it `echo`s quite a bit of data.

So in BASH I'm looking for a sort of progress or status bar of some sort that will "stick" to the bottom of the shell, I've seen this done before so I know it's possible but I've never actually messed around with stuff like this. It will only display simple data such as `Working`, `Resting`, `Stopping` and `Ran for x seconds`.

Can someone enlighten me on how to do this? The script will be run in a `screen`.

Obviously it will need some `system` calls.

Something like this:

```
----------------------------------
| data                           |
| data                           |
| data                           |
| data                           |
| data                           |
| data                           |
| data                           |
| data                           |
|--------------------------------|
|    "status bar" here           |
----------------------------------
```

Thanks in advance,
Jordan.

Answer (score 1):

Curses is your friend, many ways to do it, for an example look over here [bashsimplecurses](https://code.google.com/p/bashsimplecurses/)

Comment: There wasn't an example for a sticky footer over on their Google Code.

Comment: You didn't say you wanted someone to write the code for you. And if that's the case then this is the wrong forum.

Comment: It was stated in his post that there was an example on that site "[...] many ways to do it, for an example look over here"